# How to tell if piping a tar file as a stream to curl is streaming vs. saving to a cached file first?

Tags: pipe, tar, curl

I am trying to archive a folder using `tar` and then use `curl` to stream upload it without having to take up any space in my hard drive or memory. I have

```
tar cf - "FOLDERNAME" | curl -v -T - \
    -X PUT \
    -H "content-transfer-encoding: binary" \
    --output here.txt \
    https://www.{myuploadlink}.com/
```

which appears to work and upload the file. However, I am wondering if it is truly streaming or perhaps is it first creating the tar file, writing it to cache or memory, then uploading it? How can I tell if it is writing it to a stream, vs creating the tar file first, saving it somewhere (in memory), then uploading?

Comment: Unix pipes use an in-memory buffer so this will take _some_ space in memory. The exact amount varies depending on the variant and version of Unix used, which you didn't tell us, and sometimes on configuration options as well. However it is rarely more than a few kilobtyes, and tars are _typically_ fairly large, so _probably_ the entire tar is not present in the buffer at any point in time. In addition both of the processes will have some data in their private memory. PS: HTTP, although partly based on concepts taken from MIME, does not use the content-transfer-encoding header, and never has.

Comment: `sudo lsof -c tar;sudo lsof -c curl` while it's running. `man lsof`.

Comment: @waltinator Thank you. I have read over `man lsof`. It appears I want to look at `SIZE/OFF`. I noticed it changes as a function of time, for each time I am calling it. Is the value at `SIZE/OFF` (in bytes) the usage at any given time? Thanks!

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you, I am using CentOS and Solaris. The Solaris one is `Sun solaris 5.11` while for CentOS it is `CentOS Linux 7.6.1810`. For both OS's I have `tar (GNU tar) version 1.32` and `curl 7.45.0`.